# Postgresql: convert text representing key - value to json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table with a string column containing values like this: 'ID: 1, name: john doe, occupation: salesmen'. I want to convert this into a column of JSON objects like this: {"ID" : "1", "name" : "john doe", "occupation" : "salesmen"}

For now my solution is:

```
    WITH 
    lv1 as(SELECT regexp_split_to_table('ID: 1, name: john doe, occupation: salesmen', ', ') record)
    , lv2 as (SELECT regexp_split_to_array(record, ': ') arr from lv1)

   SELECT 
       json_object(
           array_agg(arr[1])
           , array_agg(arr[2])
       )
   FROM lv2
```

The problem is that the string actually contains nearly 100 key - value pair and the table has millions of rows, so using regex_split_to_table will make this table explode. Is there any efficient way to do this in Postgresql?

Comment: Did you check JSON functions available in PostgreSQL documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html

Comment: I did, but I want to know if there is an efficient way to accomplish what I want here. As Vao Tsun said there is no parser so I guess there is no easy way

Answer (score 0):

you don't necessarily need regular expressions functions here, eg:

```
db=# with c as (select unnest('{ID: 1, name: john doe, occupation: salesmen}'::text[]))
select string_to_array(unnest,': ') from c;
    string_to_array
-----------------------
 {ID,1}
 {name,"john doe"}
 {occupation,salesmen}
(3 rows)
```

Not sure what will be faster though.

Regarding built in json formatting - I think you HAVE to provide ether a row or formatted `JSON` - no parsers are currently vailable...